# sudo apt-get update error for ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, updates, 16.04

I try to enter `sudo apt-get udate` and I always get some error message:

```
Hit:1 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:3 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease         
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:5 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:7 http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 InRelease 
Get:8 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [212 kB]
Hit:9 http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian lsb3.2 Release   
Get:10 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [208 kB]
Get:11 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [93.4 kB]
Get:12 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [90.5 kB]
Get:13 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [85.8 kB]
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:16 http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [82.7 kB]
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                                                     
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                                        
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                 
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                    
Fetched 962 kB in 6s (141 kB/s)                                                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key F8897B6F00075648E248B7EC24CBF5474CFD1E2F uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It seems like I am not able to update it successfully. I would appreciate it if any one can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The Pinta PPA doesn't have a installation candidate for Xenial, therefore you get 404 error messages. Remove the PPA from "Software & Updates".

Comment: should I follow the following link: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed]

Comment: I removed the PPA from "Software & Updates." and I got another error: